# How to change background color of custom xml file in android

Tags: android

how to change the inner color of my xml file.It has default color as black only.how to change to other color.i have gn by xml file below .xml file is used for creating border,but i cant change the background color.Need help on this

Regards
Gomathi sankar

Answer (score 1):

There is a background property that you can set. Just change it to #ffffff to make it white.